# React native razorpay ui opening in transparent background

Tags: react-native, razorpay

I am using react-native-customui, when i am opening razorpay using below

```
const options = {
    description: 'Credits towards consultation',
    currency: 'INR',
    key_id: "rzr_id",
    amount: 100,
    email: 'void@razorpay.com',
    contact: '9999999123',
    method: 'card',
    'card[name]': 'test,
    'card[number]': 4111111111111111,
    'card[expiry_month]': 12,
    'card[expiry_year]': 23,
    'card[cvv]': 123,
  };
  Razorpay.open(options).then((res: any) => {// handle success}).catch((error: any) => {// handle failure});
```

Razorpay ui opening with transparent background, It is opening in android with normal white background.

[image]